# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'

Tags: python, updates, anaconda

my conda env working fine but when I ran `~$ conda upgrade` it suggest other command.

```
~$ conda update --prefix /home/dir1/anaconda3 anaconda
```

so I ran it and work fine but after the complete process 
when running

```
conda
```

or any other

`conda info or conda -v`

get the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dir1/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

Comment: `conda` is a Python script which tries to import stuff from the `conda` module without success. Either remove `conda` from `/usr/bin/` or make it use a Python environment where the `conda` module can be resolved.